# Reduce the latency of data transfer

Tags: linux, sockets

There are:

- an TCP server
- an TCP client.

The client contacts the server in order to obtain a file.

In case the server doesn't have the file, the server asks at other servers.

When one of these, send at the server (the first) the file, this send it at the client.

The server (the first) has to forward the file to the client gradually, as the bytes arrive from the second server (so without waiting receiving the ENTIRE file). Any Idea?

Comment: 1 global server, who knows which file on which server is located, you request the global server and you get as response the IP of the server which contains what you need, then you connect to the server returned in the response and you're downloading what you need.

Comment: "Any ideas?" is not a real question. Please tell us what you've tried, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: The problem is that the first server must act as a proxy when it doesn't have the required file.

Comment: I do the "send" (from the first Server) to the second Server in order to send the file name.
The second Server with the "recv" receives the name, calculates the size of the file, and sends this information to the first Server with the "send".
The first Server with the "malloc" allocates an dinamic array (which acts as a buffer) and do the "recv" and the second the server sends the file.
But in this way the first server receives ALL the file and then sends it to the client.

Comment: The desired behavior requires that the Client think that the file in sent from the first Server: the first server send to the client bytes per bytes as it receives it from the second server (therefore should not receive all the file and then send it to the client)

Comment: Have you tried using an existing protocol that supports that scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Hash your filenames and shard the servers based on that hash, so the client can know from the beginning which server has a particular file without asking anyone.

Comment: the problem is that this is a requirement of the project that is not under my control. l post it:

If the second server returns the requested file, the server forwards the received file to the client that requested it. The forwarding operation must be carried out with the minimum possible latency, ie, the
server needs to forward to the client file data As they arrive on the other server (without waiting
receiving the entire file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "direct server return" to avoid the response data going through the first server. How to implement it depends on what your communication protocol is like and how your storage and your network is set up.

Here's a similar question, using http. Some answers assume a shared storage so that it doesnt matter which of the backend servers responds. https://serverfault.com/questions/112667/forwarding-http-request-with-direct-server-return